# Getting error while implementing DCGAN in pytorch: Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I have been trying to train a DCGAN implementation in PyTorch. I am getting the following error:

> **RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (3 x 3). Kernel size: (4 x 4). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size**

I have modified the discriminator network defined in [this implementation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html).

The modified discriminator network is as follows:

```
self.main = nn.Sequential(
           
            nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, ndf * 16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 16),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 16, ndf * 16, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 16),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 16, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is probably not here but in the way you pass your input to the sequential. The padded image is too small, only 3x3 pixels, hence you cannot use a kernel 4x4.

Comment: @Neb Thanks for sharing. I am still not able to debug it. The rest of the code is the same as [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html). I have just tried to modify the layers.